# What I've done wrong with dragging columns vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuedraggable

What is sortable? Why I got problem with it

[image: This is the problem what I've got]

```
  sortTheHeadersAndUpdateTheKey(evt) {
    const headersTmp = this.headers;
    const oldIndex = evt.oldIndex;
    const newIndex = evt.newIndex;
    if (newIndex >= headersTmp.length) {
      let k = newIndex - headersTmp.length + 1;
      while (k--) {
        headersTmp.push(undefined);
      }
    }
    headersTmp.splice(newIndex, 0, headersTmp.splice(oldIndex, 1)[0]);
    this.table = headersTmp;
    this.anIncreasingNumber += 1;
  },
},
directives: {
  'sortable-table': {
    inserted: (el, binding) => {
      el.querySelectorAll('th').forEach((draggableEl) => {
        // Need a class watcher because sorting v-data-table rows asc/desc removes the sortHandle class
        watchClass(draggableEl, 'sortHandle');
        draggableEl.classList.add('sortHandle');
      });
      Sortable.create(el.querySelector('tr'), binding.value ? { ...binding.value, handle: '.sortHandle' } : {});
    },
  },
},
  <v-data-table
      :headers="showHeaders"
      :page="page"
      :pageCount="numberOfPages"
      :options.sync="options"
      :loading="loading"
      :server-items-length="totalItems"
      :items="items"
      :items-per-page="15"
      class="mainTable"
      @dblclick:row="editItem"
      v-sortable-table="{onEnd:sortTheHeadersAndUpdateTheKey}"
      :key="anIncreasingNumber"
      :footer-props="{
  showFirstLastPage: true,
  firstIcon: 'mdi-arrow-collapse-left',
  lastIcon: 'mdi-arrow-collapse-right',
  prevIcon: 'mdi-minus',
  nextIcon: 'mdi-plus'
}"
  >
```

I'm just try to do this [Dragging columns in a Vuetify v-data-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58238835/dragging-columns-in-a-vuetify-v-data-table)
but have a mistake I did all what he say and still got a problem I've installed and import vuedraggable

maybe import is wrong ---> import 'vuedraggable'

Comment: at least you should read your code before copying from somewhere.

Comment: Sortable is the javascript library you're trying to use, which you haven't installed or imported. It doesn't come with vue. The question you linked to says to install Sortable, I'd start with reading the answer and making an attempt to understand it. Also don't post text in images, post them as text.